# adding into SQLite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

I'm trying to add multiple items to database. However, during read operation, I getting always the last item. I got many item as I added. However, they have same content of last item added.

Example:

```
06-03 18:30:19.343 16360-16360/com.example.wince.myapplication D/add: Yer [id=112, name=syndey, lat=-34.0, lng=151.0]
06-03 18:30:19.393 16360-16360/com.example.wince.myapplication D/add: Yer [id=112, name=syndey, lat=-34.0, lng=151.0]
06-03 18:30:19.433 16360-16360/com.example.wince.myapplication D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1776K, 49% free 10398K/20120K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
06-03 18:30:19.443 16360-16360/com.example.wince.myapplication D/add: Yer [id=112, name=syndey, lat=-34.0, lng=151.0]
06-03 18:30:19.483 16360-16360/com.example.wince.myapplication D/add: Yer [id=112, name=syndey, lat=-34.0, lng=151.0]
06-03 18:30:19.504 16360-16360/com.example.wince.myapplication D/add: Yer [id=112, name=istanbul, lat=-34.0, lng=151.0]
06-03 18:30:19.534 16360-16360/com.example.wince.myapplication D/add: Yer [id=112, name=vggg, lat=-34.0, lng=151.0]
06-03 18:30:19.554 16360-16360/com.example.wince.myapplication D/add: Yer [id=112, name=ankara, lat=-34.0, lng=151.0]
06-03 18:30:19.584 16360-16360/com.example.wince.myapplication D/add: Yer [id=112, name=bagdat, lat=-34.0, lng=151.0]
```

What I read is:

```
D/getAllBooks(): [Yer [id=120, name=bagdat, lat=-34.0, lng=151.0], 
    Yer [id=120, name=bagdat, lat=-34.0, lng=151.0], 
    Yer [id=120, name=bagdat, lat=-34.0, lng=151.0], 
    Yer [id=120, name=bagdat, lat=-34.0, lng=151.0], 
    Yer [id=120, name=bagdat, lat=-34.0, lng=151.0], 
    Yer [id=120, name=bagdat, lat=-34.0, lng=151.0], 
    Yer [id=120, name=bagdat, lat=-34.0, lng=151.0], 
    Yer [id=120, name=bagdat, lat=-34.0, lng=151.0],
....
```

This is how I add them to database

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog2, int which) {
    m_Text = input.getText().toString();
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    VT.add(new Yer("syndey", sydney.latitude, sydney.longitude));
    VT.add(new Yer("syndey", sydney.latitude, sydney.longitude));
    VT.add(new Yer("syndey", sydney.latitude, sydney.longitude));
    VT.add(new Yer("syndey", sydney.latitude, sydney.longitude));
    VT.add(new Yer("istanbul", sydney.latitude, sydney.longitude));
    VT.add(new Yer(m_Text, sydney.latitude, sydney.longitude));
    VT.add(new Yer("ankara", sydney.latitude, sydney.longitude));
    VT.add(new Yer("bagdat", sydney.latitude, sydney.longitude));
}
```

i just use getall fucntion to get them.

and this is my helper class.

```
package com.example.wince.myapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Wince on 2.06.2016.
 */
public class VeriTabani extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //  table name
    private static final String TABLE = "Kayitlar";

    //  Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "isim";
    private static final String KEY_LAT = "latitude";
    private static final String KEY_LNG = "longitude";

    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,KEY_LAT,KEY_LNG};
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "KayitDB";

    public VeriTabani(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // SQL statement to create  table
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE Kayitlar ( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "isim TEXT, " +
                "latitude REAL,"+
                "longitude REAL )";

        // create kayıtlar table
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older books table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ");

        // create fresh books table
        this.onCreate(db);
    }
    public void add(Yer veri){
        //for logging
        Log.d("add", veri.toString());

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, Yer.getName()); // get title
        values.put(KEY_LAT,Yer.getLat() ); // get author
        values.put(KEY_LNG,Yer.getLng());

        // 3. insert
        db.insert(TABLE, // table
                null, //nullColumnHack
                values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column values

        // 4. close
        db.close();
    }
    public Yer getYer(int id){

        // 1. get reference to readable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        // 2. build query
        Cursor cursor =
                db.query(TABLE, // a. table
                        COLUMNS, // b. column names
                        " id = ?", // c. selections
                        new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, // d. selections args
                        null, // e. group by
                        null, // f. having
                        null, // g. order by
                        null); // h. limit

        // 3. if we got results get the first one
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        // 4. build  object
        Yer yer = new Yer();
        yer.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        yer.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        yer.setLat(cursor.getDouble(2));
        yer.setLng(cursor.getDouble(3));

        Log.d("getBook("+id+")", yer.toString());

        // 5. return
        return yer;
    }

    // Get All
    public List<Yer> getAllYer() {
        List<Yer> yerler = new LinkedList<Yer>();

        // 1. build the query
        String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE;

        // 2. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        // 3. go over each row, build book and add it to list
        Yer yer = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                yer = new Yer();
                yer.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                yer.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                yer.setLat(cursor.getDouble(2));
                yer.setLng(cursor.getDouble(3));

                // Add book to books
                yerler.add(yer);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        Log.d("getAllBooks()", yerler.toString());

        // return books
        return yerler;
    }

    // Updating single
    public int updateBook(Yer yer) {

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("Name", yer.getName()); // get title
        values.put("Lat", yer.getLat()); // get author
        values.put("Lng",yer.getLng());

        // 3. updating row
        int i = db.update(TABLE, //table
                values, // column/value
                KEY_ID+" = ?", // selections
                new String[] { String.valueOf(yer.getId()) }); //selection args

        // 4. close
        db.close();

        return i;

    }

    // Deleting single
    public void deleteBook(Yer yer) {

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. delete
        db.delete(TABLE,
                KEY_ID+" = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(yer.getId()) });

        // 3. close
        db.close();

        Log.d("deleteBook", yer.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you display the results?

Comment: @Chol I think he is printing the list in getAllBooks()

Comment: @GuilhermeP Right :)

Comment: @GuilhermeP im printing log for each step as u see at last code block

Comment: Try maybe with  yerler.add(new Yer(...));

Comment: @chol u mean in main or the helper class?

Comment: @Wince Please, share the implementation of Yer class.. share only the header and variable members declaration...

Comment: When adding the yer object to your list in the do/while

Comment: @chol its already done so a bit above  there u can see yer is actualy new Yer

Comment: @GuilhermeP public class Yer {

    static private int id;
    static private Double Lng;
    static private Double Lat;
    static private String Name; 

not sure what u meant with header but variables are this

Comment: @Wince check my answer. I think the problem are the Yen variable members... they are static. So, all objects are sharing same memory position (and consequently, show only the last value saved)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is your Yen class

```
static private int id; 
static private Double Lng; 
static private Double Lat; 
static private String Name
```

I think the problem are the Yen variable members... they are static. So, all objects are sharing same memory position (and consequently, show only the last value saved)

Remove static modifier of those Yen class members

Comment: yeah, that can be the issue!

Comment: yes seems this was the issue thought now im getting done with app freeze due to too many reads lol. Ty

Comment: any ideas if this could hava caused the getall function to stop working?

Comment: Code that you shared seems OK. I'm not sure if the database is too large which can freeze the UI during query (specially in Low/Mid tier devices). You really must remove the "static" modifier.. Now, you should try to find the bottleneck... DB size... Too many yen elements in memory etc...

Comment: @GuilhermeP i tried something else and it seems now i read all the values as null  , 0 , 0 gotta figure out if it fails at adding the variables in database or just reading.

Comment: Yes... Do that.. Always print the variable directly from cursor.. if cursor has the wrong values, problem is the values saved in database... if cursor is right, then, your Yen object has errors (probalby with get/set methods)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {     
                // Add book to books
                yerler.add(new Yer(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                                   cursor.getString(1),
                                   cursor.getDouble(2),
                                   cursor.getDouble(3)));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
```

Comment: should i use it on the sme spot other guy suggested? if so it doesnt resolve the constructor

Comment: You need to add a constructor with the id. But try the Guilherme solution first